# MACOS python package installation problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, gcc, package

I'm trying to install "supplychainpy" package for python but i get a gcc error. *"error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1"*

- Yes, I have installed the xcode devtools `xcode-select --install`
- Yes, I'm sure gcc is present `gcc --version`
- Yes, my pip is up to date `pip install --upgrade pip`
- Yes, I have gcc installed (with `brew install gcc`).
- Yes i have anaconda package installed with all the dependancies.

This does not help. This is the output i get:

```
    running build_ext
      building 'supplychainpy.simulations.sim_summary' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/supplychainpy
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/supplychainpy/simulations
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c supplychainpy/simulations/sim_summary.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/supplychainpy/simulations/sim_summary.o
      supplychainpy/simulations/sim_summary.c:6785:34: warning: variable '__pyx_v_f' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
        __pyx_t_1 = PyFloat_FromDouble(__pyx_v_f); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(0, 296, __pyx_L1_error)
                                       ^~~~~~~~~
      supplychainpy/simulations/sim_summary.c:6771:18: note: initialize the variable '__pyx_v_f' to silence this warning
        float __pyx_v_f;
                       ^
                        = 0.0
      supplychainpy/simulations/sim_summary.c:8290:65: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 3, have 4
          return (*((__Pyx_PyCFunctionFast)meth)) (self, args, nargs, NULL);
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                     ^~~~
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:105:16: note: expanded from macro 'NULL'
      #  define NULL ((void*)0)
                     ^~~~~~~~~~
      1 warning and 1 error generated.
      error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

     Failed building wheel for supplychainpy
  Running setup.py clean for supplychainpy
Failed to build supplychainpy
Installing collected packages: supplychainpy
  Running setup.py install for supplychainpy ... error
    Complete output from command /anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/m2/c5429khn3pj5581m817y69qc0000gn/T/pip-install-nrjs0muv/supplychainpy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/m2/c5429khn3pj5581m817y69qc0000gn/T/pip-record-md9iewfc/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Sorry, this isn't helpful, but: That looks weird, it looks like it's using Clang headers. I'm not a Mac user - is that normal behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be the gcc compiler config. You can download the compiled `.whl` 
 file from https://pypi.org/project/supplychainpy/#files. Note that `*-macosx_10_6_x86_64.whl` files are for macosx.

Comment: I've tried to do this but i get this: `supplychainpy-0.0.5-cp35-cp35m-macosx_10_6_x86_644.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Comment: @AleksandrTerekhov The wheel file is suitable for py3.5. Maybe you can create a py3.5 environment. ( Not a good solution, but fast.)